# How to create a custom AWS Alexa skill using my exported Dialogflow (API.AI) agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, dialogflow-es

I have a Dialogflow (formerly called API.AI) agent that works great in Dialogflow -- I can have a multi-level conversation that persists contexts, etc. I've been struggling to export this into an Alexa skill, which I believe should be possible. The Dialogflow docs only provide the steps to export the intents/sample utterances, which I have in my Alexa skill. I've been trying to find examples of a Lambda function that will actually use my Dialogflow-exported intents and sample utterances, but I haven't found anything that shows me how to do that. So far I've only found examples that return hard-coded responses (not actually using a response from my Dialogflow agent). I've tried [this](https://github.com/Gnzlt/AlexaApiAiBridge) Node.js example, which will recognize my default welcome intent but none of my other Dialogflow intents. (I get the fallback intent - "Sorry, what was that?") Has anyone done this before or knows of something I'm missing?

Comment: Did You find any solution?